# forestplot use different shapes or colors

Tags: r, r-forestplot

I want to create a plot that has adjusted values (top line for each stratum) and matched values (line represented by X in each stratum) across all strata eg men, women, age <55, age >55 etc. For the matched values, I'd like to have a diamond/other shape or different colour to highlight. But not sure how to do?

I realise I could use this example http://gforge.se/2013/12/the-forestplot-of-dreams/  to make two separate datasets, one for adjusted values and one for matched values, and then combine - but would rather not have to input all values again.

Can someone please help edit the third section of my code to make a diff shape or diff colour for the matched values in my graph (matched vals are the lines represented by X in the N column).

```
 library(forestplot)
main_acevccb <- 
  structure(list(
    mean  = c(NA, NA, NA, -1.12, -0.64, -1.55,-1.60, NA, -1.35,-1.44, -1.3, -1.2, NA, -1.29,-1.23, -2.82,-2.15, -1.84,-2.72), 
    lower = c(NA, NA, NA, -1.41, -0.84, -1.85, -1.86, NA, -1.71,-1.9, -1.57,-1.52, NA, -1.53, -1.54, -4.04, -3.61, -2.85,-4.45),
    upper = c(NA, NA, NA, -0.83, -0.44, -1.26, -1.34, NA, -1.0, -0.98,-1.04, -0.87, NA, -1.04,-0.93, -1.59,-0.68, -0.82, -0.99)),
    .Names = c("Difference", "lower", "upper"), 
    row.names = c(NA, -19L), 
    class = "data.frame")

tabletext_acevccb<-cbind(
  c("", "Analysis", "", "Male", "", "Female","", "", "Aged <55yrs","",  "Aged >=55yrs", "", "", "White", "", "Black", "", "South Asian", ""),
  c("", "N", NA, "146,763", "X",  "123,425", "X", NA, "104,584","X", "165,604", "X", NA, "258,565", "X", "4,115", "X", "5,148", "X"), 
  c(NA, "Diff Sys BP 
    CCB vs ACE/ARB", NA, "-1.12","-0.64", "-1.55", "-1.60", NA, "-1.35", "-1.44", "-1.30", "-1.20", NA, "-1.29","-1.23",  "-2.82", "-2.15", "-1.84", "-2.72"), 
  c(NA, "95% CI", NA,"-1.41 : -0.83", "-0.84 : -0.44", "-1.85 : -1.26", "-1.86 : -1.34", NA, "-1.71 : -1.0", "-1.90 : -0.98", "-1.57 : -1.04", "-1.52 : -0.87", NA, "-1.53 : -1.04", "-1.54 : -0.93", "-4.04 : -1.59", "-3.61 : -0.68", "-2.85 : -0.82", "-4.45 : -0.99"))

forestplot(tabletext_acevccb, 
           main_acevccb,new_page = TRUE,    
           hrzl_lines=list("3" = gpar(lwd=1, col="#444444")), 
           is.summary=c(TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, rep(FALSE, 16)),
           txt_gp = fpTxtGp(label=gpar(cex=0.7)
           ),
           boxsize=0.25,
           xlog=F, 
           graphwidth = unit(7.5, "cm"),
           clip= c(-3.5, 0.5),
           xticks=c(-3.5, -3.0, -2.5, -2.0, -1.5, -1.0, -0.5 , 0, 0.5),
           col=fpColors(box="royalblue",line="darkblue"))
```

EDIT
Below is the code to provide graph as per below advice. Thank you for suggesting this.  However, to maintain the "n", "diff" and "95% CI" as per my above graph - I think my question can be simplified to "how can I amend my col=fpColors code above to paint each box a different color?"

```
 main_acevccb <- structure(list(
   analysis = c( "Male","Male", "Female", "Female", NA, "<55", "<55", ">55", ">55",NA, "White", "White", "Black","Black", "SA", "SA"),
   mean  = c( -1.12, -0.64, -1.55,-1.60, NA, -1.35,-1.44, -1.3, -1.2, NA, -1.29,-1.23, -2.82,-2.15, -1.84,-2.72), 
    lower = c( -1.41, -0.84, -1.85, -1.86, NA, -1.71,-1.9, -1.57,-1.52, NA, -1.53, -1.54, -4.04, -3.61, -2.85,-4.45),
    upper = c( -0.83, -0.44, -1.26, -1.34, NA, -1.0, -0.98,-1.04, -0.87, NA, -1.04,-0.93, -1.59,-0.68, -0.82, -0.99),
    type = c( "adjusted", "matched","adjusted", "matched", NA, "adjusted", "matched","adjusted", "matched", NA, "adjusted", "matched","adjusted", "matched", "adjusted", "matched")),
    .Names = c("Analysis","Difference", "lower", "upper", "type"), 
    row.names = (c(NA, -16L)), 
    class = "data.frame")


adjusted <- subset(main_acevccb, type!="matched"|is.na(type))
matched  <- subset(main_acevccb, type!="adjusted"|is.na(type))


forestplot(mean=cbind(adjusted[,"Difference"], matched[,"Difference"]),
           lower=cbind(adjusted[,"lower"], matched[,"lower"]), 
           upper=cbind(adjusted[,"upper"], matched[,"upper"]), 
           labeltext=matched$Analysis,
          legend=c("Adjusted", "Matched"),
          legend.pos=("bottomright"),           
          legend.gp = gpar(col="#AAAAAA"), 
          legend.r=unit(.1, "snpc"),
            fn.ci_norm = c(fpDrawNormalCI, fpDrawCircleCI),
           boxsize = .30, 
           line.margin = .5, 
           clip=c(-4.0, 1.0), 
           xticks=c(-4.0, -3.5, -3.0, -2.5, -2.0, -1.5, -1.0, -0.5, 0, 0.5, 1),
           col=fpColors(box=c("darkblue", "darkred")),
           xlab="Diff in Systolic BP CCB vs ACE-I/ARB",
           new_page=TRUE)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*I realise I could use this example http://gforge.se/2013/12/the-forestplot-of-dreams/ to make two separate datasets, one for adjusted values and one for matched values, and then combine - but would rather not have to input all values again.*

**Option 1**        If you want to stick with `forestplot` I think the solution described in link you mentioned (or [here](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/forestplot/vignettes/forestplot.html#multiple-confidence-bands)) is optimal . 
You don´t have to type all the data - just add an extra column to your dataframe and then subset it.

```
# You can add the column like this: 
type = c(NA, NA, NA, "adjusted", "matched","adjusted", "matched", NA, "adjusted", "matched","adjusted", "matched", NA, "adjusted", "matched","adjusted", "matched", "adjusted", "matched")

# So your dataframe will look like this: 
main_acevccb <- structure(list(
    mean  = c(NA, NA, NA, -1.12, -0.64, -1.55,-1.60, NA, -1.35,-1.44, -1.3, -1.2, NA, -1.29,-1.23, -2.82,-2.15, -1.84,-2.72), 
    lower = c(NA, NA, NA, -1.41, -0.84, -1.85, -1.86, NA, -1.71,-1.9, -1.57,-1.52, NA, -1.53, -1.54, -4.04, -3.61, -2.85,-4.45),
    upper = c(NA, NA, NA, -0.83, -0.44, -1.26, -1.34, NA, -1.0, -0.98,-1.04, -0.87, NA, -1.04,-0.93, -1.59,-0.68, -0.82, -0.99),
    type = c(NA, NA, NA, "adjusted", "matched","adjusted", "matched", NA, "adjusted", "matched","adjusted", "matched", NA, "adjusted", "matched","adjusted", "matched", "adjusted", "matched")),
   .Names = c("Difference", "lower", "upper", "type"), 
   row.names = c(NA, -19L), 
   class = "data.frame")

# ...and then you subset it:
adjusted <- subset(main_acevccb, type!="matched"|is.na(type))
matched  <- subset(main_acevccb, type!="adjusted"|is.na(type))
```

Then you´ll have two separate dataframes for adjusted and matched values and can proceed as described in the link. However, with that method you can either have text OR different colors.

**Option 2** If you want to have both, the text labels for each row AND different colors, you could try `ggplot`:

```
# add 2 extra columns to your dataframe
y=c(19, 18, 17, 16, 15, 14,13, 12, 11,10, 9, 8, 7, 6,5, 4,3, 2,1),
Analysis=c("","","", "Male", "Male","Female","Female", "", "Aged <55yrs","Aged <55yrs",  "Aged >=55yrs", "Aged >=55yrs", "", "White", "White", "Black", "Black", "South Asian", "South Asian")),

# so it will look like this:
main_acevccb <- 
  structure(list(
    mean  = c(NA, NA, NA, -1.12, -0.64, -1.55,-1.60, NA, -1.35,-1.44, -1.3, -1.2, NA, -1.29,-1.23, -2.82,-2.15, -1.84,-2.72), 
    lower = c(NA, NA, NA, -1.41, -0.84, -1.85, -1.86, NA, -1.71,-1.9, -1.57,-1.52, NA, -1.53, -1.54, -4.04, -3.61, -2.85,-4.45),
    upper = c(NA, NA, NA, -0.83, -0.44, -1.26, -1.34, NA, -1.0, -0.98,-1.04, -0.87, NA, -1.04,-0.93, -1.59,-0.68, -0.82, -0.99),
    type = c(NA, NA, NA, "adjusted", "matched","adjusted", "matched", NA, "adjusted", "matched","adjusted", "matched", NA, "adjusted", "matched","adjusted", "matched", "adjusted", "matched"),
    y=c(19, 18, 17, 16, 15, 14,13, 12, 11,10, 9, 8, 7, 6,5, 4,3, 2,1),
    Analysis=c("","","", "Male", "Male","Female","Female", "", "Aged <55yrs","Aged <55yrs",  "Aged >=55yrs", "Aged >=55yrs", "", "White", "White", "Black", "Black", "South Asian", "South Asian")),
  .Names = c("Difference", "lower", "upper", "type", "y", "Analysis"), 
    row.names = c(NA, -19L), 
    class = "data.frame")

# and make a graph with ggplot
p <- ggplot(data=main_acevccb,
       aes(x = type,y = Difference, ymin = lower, ymax = upper ))+
  geom_pointrange(aes(col=type))+
  geom_hline(aes(fill=type),yintercept =0, linetype=2)+
  xlab('Type')+ ylab("Your axis title)")+
  geom_errorbar(aes(ymin=lower, ymax=upper,col=type),width=0.5,cex=1)+
  facet_wrap(~Analysis,strip.position="left",nrow=9,scales = "free_y") +
  theme(plot.title=element_text(size=16,face="bold"),
    axis.text.y=element_blank(),
    axis.ticks.y=element_blank(),
    axis.text.x=element_text(face="bold"),
    axis.title=element_text(size=12,face="bold"),
    strip.text.y = element_text(hjust=0,vjust = 1,angle=180,face="bold"))+
  coord_flip()
p <- p+ylim(-5, 5)

# and finally add the text labels (modify it to get the labels you want) 
p <- p+geom_text(label=c(rep("Difference (CI95%)")), y=1, hjust="left")  
p
```

Comment: thank you so much for this suggestion. I've posted my answer code above. However, I'm a bit lost as to how to add additional columns to this graph eg "n", "Diff" and "95% CI" as I outlined in my original graph above. @MaxGordon's code (provided in links above) suggests making a matrix and appending additional info to row names. This is complex for me as I have so many cols I want to add. Have you any ideas on how I could easily do this?

Comment: I think I´ve seen methods for adding either the text columns OR multiple graph symbols, but not both at the same time. Technically speaking, you have Diff and 95% shown on graph already, so they are a redundancy which you can maybe leave out (?).  Sample size you can include in the main group name like "Males (n=x)". Or you can have it in a column. What would be problematic is to get text labels for both, adjusted and matched  groups..

Comment: I take your point on redundancy, but is essential that I present these data. The n cannot be just added to the main group name (eg male n=x) because the n are different for adjusted and matched. So I really do need to add additional columns. The code I presented above does this, but does let me highlight matched groups by using different shapes/different colours. This is why I was hoping for an amendment to my original code.

Comment: I think the solution is probably to use the original code I have listed above but vary the box colours with code similar to the following: col=fpColors(box="royalblue", "green", "yellow", "red", "purple", "pink", "orange","royalblue", "green", "yellow", "red", "purple", "pink", "orange")). This bit of code doesn't actually work, but I suspect this is where the solution is.

Comment: Have you seen anywhere that it has been done with this package? I´ve seen solutions with ggplot which achieve the same outcome, but not with forestplot... One way could be to make a separate graph and a table for n/Diff/CI95% values (you can even join them into two-panel graph).

Comment: if I use my original code and use this line          " fn.ci_norm =c(fpDrawCircleCI,fpDrawNormalCI,fpDrawCircleCI,fpDrawNormalCI,fpDrawCircleCI,fpDrawNormalCI,fpDrawCircleCI,fpDrawNormalCI,fpDrawCircleCI,fpDrawNormalCI,fpDrawCircleCI,fpDrawNormalCI,fpDrawCircleCI,fpDrawNormalCI)", 
I can get diff shapes for my adjusted and matched values. Still no joy on getting different colours though. :(

Comment: I edited my answer to include a solution with ggplot2 and both - different colors and text labels

Comment: @user2363642  have you tried it or managed to get it to work with either of solutions?